# Null with Array java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The program asks the user for a bill and then how much they paid for it and is supposed to calculate and print out the change. I left off the second part because my problem I have is with the calculation of the change in the second for loop. The error occurring is `java.lang.NullPointerException` on a different dime, quarter, nickel line etc. depending on the user inputs. I've looked up the problem and people say its the program trying to grab a value that is `null` but I don't see how because i is updating.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    Double[] Bill = new Double[5];
    Double[] Paid = new Double[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int j = i + 1;
        System.out.print("Enter bill " + j + ": ");
        Bill[i] = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter amount paid for bill " + j + ": ");
        Paid[i] = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine())
        System.out.println("");        
    }

    Integer[] Dollars = new Integer[5];
    Integer[] Quarters = new Integer[5];
    Integer[] Dimes = new Integer[5];
    Integer[] Nickels = new Integer[5];
    Integer[] Pennies = new Integer[5];   
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
       Double Change = Paid[i] - Bill[i];

       while (Change > 0){
           if (Change > 1){
               Change = Change - 1;
               Dollars[i] = Dollars[i] + 1;   
           }
           else if (Change > 0.25){
               Change = Change - 0.25;
               Quarters[i] = Quarters[i] + 1;
           }
           else if (Change > .1){
               Change = Change - 0.1;
               Dimes[i] = Dimes[i] + 1;
           }
           else if (Change > .05){
               Change = Change - 0.05;
               Nickels[i] = Nickels[i] + 1;
           }
           else if (Change > 0){
               Change = Change = 0.01;
               Pennies[i] = Pennies[i] + 1;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Error Stack Trace Please?

Answer (score 0):

By virtue of creating a new array, you're creating only the *space* for the elements, but not instantiating anything *inside* of it.  Arrays initialize its elements with default values, [and the default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for all reference types - or objects - is `null`.

Any line that does any sort of auto-unboxing - namely this one:

```
Dollars[i] = Dollars[i] + 1;
```

Will result in a `NullPointerException`, since the value in `Dollars[i]` isn't initialized to anything - it's `null` by default.

Initialize the value in each of your arrays to something sane.  For instance, you could have a method that only initializes `Integer[]` elements to `Integer.valueOf(0)`.

```
public void initializeArrays(Integer[] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = Integer.valueOf(0);
    }
}
```

Call that before using any of the values in the array.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8), emphasis mine:  A `null` boxed value that is unboxed results in a `NullPointerException`.

> Unboxing conversion converts expressions of reference type to
>   corresponding expressions of primitive type. Specifically, the
>   following eight conversions are called the unboxing conversions:
>
> - From type Boolean to type boolean
> - From type Byte to type byte
> - From type Short to type short
> - From type Character to type char
> - From type Integer to type int
> - From type Long to type long
> - From type Float to type float
> - From type Double to type double
>
> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> - If r is a reference of type Boolean, then unboxing conversion converts
>     r into r.booleanValue()
> - If r is a reference of type Byte, then unboxing conversion converts r
>     into r.byteValue()
> - If r is a reference of type Character, then unboxing conversion
>     converts r into r.charValue()
>
> If r is a reference of type Short, then unboxing conversion converts r
>   into r.shortValue()
>
> - If r is a reference of type Integer, then unboxing conversion converts
>     r into r.intValue()
> - If r is a reference of type Long, then unboxing conversion converts r
>     into r.longValue()
> - If r is a reference of type Float, unboxing conversion converts r into
>     r.floatValue()
> - If r is a reference of type Double, then unboxing conversion converts
>     r into r.doubleValue()
> - **If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException**

Answer (score 0):

Before initializing Dollar reference variable , initially it is containing null means it is not pointing to any object and while containing null if we try to access then it will give `Null pointer exception` as in your above program.